# how to change the subject for Django error reporting emails?

Tags: python, django

i noticed about to change the subject for django error reporting emails, 
is  it possible to change subject?
can we modify the subject for Django error reporting emails ?

Comment: You can prefix the subject with [EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#email-subject-prefix)

Answer (score 18):

You need to set the `EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX` variable in your Django settings file.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#email-subject-prefix

> `EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX`
>
> Default: `'[Django] '`
>
> Subject-line prefix for email messages sent with `django.core.mail.mail_admins` or `django.core.mail.mail_managers`. You’ll probably want to include the trailing space.

If you don't like Django error emails and want a better way of handling them, take a look a [Sentry](http://sentry.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Comment: Alternatively, you can write an alternative [AdminEmailHandler](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/log.py#L81) and plug it into your [logging configuration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/logging/).

Comment: actually, the default is `[Django] `, with a trailing space, that you probably want to have also in your custom `EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX`

Answer (score 4):

If you need it only for reporting errors the best choice would be to inherit from the `django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler` and override the `def format_subject(self, subject):` method.

Note that changing `EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX` will affect not only error emails but all emails send to admins including system information emails or so.